# Android Contentview giving me errors

Tags: android, database

This is driving my crazy, it is giving me values error pre compile on code.

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final Activity d = mActivity.get();
            if (d != null) {
                Db db = new Db(d.getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    // db.copyDbToDevice(R.raw.probes, Db.DB_PROBES);
                    db.copyDbToDevice(R.raw.services, Db.DB_SERVICES);
                    db.copyDbToDevice(R.raw.saves, Db.DB_SAVES);
                    // Save this device in db
                    com.workman.ping.Network.NetInfo net =
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("_id", 0);
                    if (net.macAddress == null) {
                        net.macAddress = com.workman.ping.Network.NetInfo.NOMAC;
                    }
                    values.put("mac", net.macAddress.replace(":", "").toUpperCase());
                    values.put("name", d.getString(R.string.discover_myphone_name));
                    SQLiteDatabase data = Db.openDb(Db.DB_SAVES);
                    data.insert("nic", null, values);
                    data.close();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        if (e.getMessage() != null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown IOException");
                        }
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This part of the code is flagging errors under all instances of values. Values keep insisting that expression is expected. Im not sure what the issue is.

```
com.workman.ping.Network.NetInfo net =
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("_id", 0);
                    if (net.macAddress == null) {
                        net.macAddress = com.workman.ping.Network.NetInfo.NOMAC;
                    }
                    values.put("mac", net.macAddress.replace(":", "").toUpperCase());
                    values.put("name", d.getString(R.string.discover_myphone_name));
```

Comment: Have you tried working it through IP?

Comment: Its a pre run issue, the field "values" says expecting expression when = to com.workman.ping.Network.Netinfo

Comment: The line with `com.workman.ping.Network.NetInfo =` is only half a statement. You're not assigning a value to the variable.

Comment: `com.workman.ping.Network.NetInfo net = ContentValues values = new ContentValues();` **??**